# Increasing sequence of measure defines a measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

I was wondering if the following is a correct way to prove it. Thank you.

> Let $(X,\mathscr{A})$ a measurable space and let $\{\mu_n\}$ and increasing sequence of measures on $(X,\mathscr{A})$ such that $\lim_n \mu(A)$ always exists for all $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ and $A$ in $\mathscr{A}$. Defines the limit as $\mu$. Show that $\mu$ is a measure on $(X,\mathscr{A})$

It is clear that $\mu(\varnothing)=0$. Now let $\{A_n\}$ a sequence of disjoint subset of $X$ which belongs to $\mathscr{A}$. Then

\begin{align*} \mu\left(\bigcup A_n\right)=\lim_k \sum_n \mu_k(A_n) \end{align*}

If we can show that $\lim_k \sum_n \mu_k(A_n)= \sum_n \mu(A_n)$ the result follows.

Let define the measure space $(\mathbb{N}, 2^{\mathbb{N}}, c)$, where $c$ is the counting measure and define the functions $f,f_n: \mathbb{N}\to [0,+\infty]$ for all $k$ in $\mathbb{N}$, as follows $f_k (n)=\mu_k(A_n)$, and similarly $f(n)= \mu(A_n)$. Then, we can write both functions as elementary functions, that is

\begin{align*} f_k(n) =\sum_m \mu_k(A_m) \chi_m (n),  \hspace{10 pt} f(n) =\sum_m \mu(A_m) \chi_m (n) \end{align*}

It is clear that $f_k$ and $f$ are $2^{\mathbb {N}}$-measurable and also $0\le f_k \uparrow f$ (that is, $\lim_k  f_k =f$ and $f_k \le f_{k+1}$). Now using the monotone convergence theorem we have $0\le \int f_k dc\uparrow \int fdc$ and by the Beppo-Levi Thm, it follows that

\begin{align*} \int_{\mathbb{N}} f dc =\int_{\mathbb{N}}\left( \sum_m \mu(A_m) \chi_m (n) \right)dc =\sum_m \mu(A_m)&=\lim_k \int_{\mathbb{N}} f_k dc\\
&=\lim_k \sum_m \mu(A_m)\end{align*}

Hence $\mu$ is a measure on $(X,\mathscr{A})$.

Comment: It's correct except for a small (non-mathematical) detail. It's not "Beppo-Levi", it's "Beppo Levi". Beppo is the first name, Levi the surname.